# RestTemplate with Bearer Authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

Is it possible to create with RestTemplateBuilder an instance of RestTemplate with just the bearer header and token?

I know i can use RestTemplate exchange and set inside the HttpEntity my headers but is it possible to do something like this:

```java
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(){
    RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
    return builder.build().exchange().setBearerAuth("token here"); //this is not possible
}
```

Hope you understand what i want to do.

Answer (score 6):

As [lilalinux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410212/lilalinux) pointed out in the comment - Authorization is the name of the header and Bearer + the token itself are the value.

```
@Bean(name = "myRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate collectCentRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.rootUri("some uri")
            .additionalInterceptors((ClientHttpRequestInterceptor) (request, body, execution) -> {
                request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                return execution.execute(request, body);
            }).build();
}
```

Comment: Additionally, like in linalinux's comment, there should be a space after "Bearer". i.e. "Bearer " + token

Answer (score 4):

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization" , "Bearer token");
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<(headers);

    ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("url");
    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(),
                HttpMethod.GET,
                entity, Object.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can try this one.

Comment: `new HttpEntity<(headers);` ← missing `>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use interceptors to inject the token to the request headers like so

```java
    @Bean(name = "myRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate someRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.rootUri("some uri")
                .additionalInterceptors((ClientHttpRequestInterceptor) (request, body, execution) -> {
                    request.getHeaders().add("Bearer", "token");
                    return execution.execute(request, body);
                }).build();
    }
```

And from your app, you can simply use it like this:

```java
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myRestTemplate")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Keep in mind you can still use the `restTemplate` object as usual, setting headers and etc, **but** the `Bearer` header will always be overridden with `"token"` because the interceptors apply right before the request is made.

Comment: When i call this RestTemplate, can i still add more headers and my body like usual?

Comment: @svrdoljak, yes, but the `Bearer` header will always be override

Comment: The header should probably be: request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token), i.e. Bearer in the value part before the token and "Authorization" as the name of the header.

Answer (score 0):

No, it was suggested and [declined](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11708) (*Provide convenience methods for Headers in RestTemplateBuilder*)

> I think the easiest way at the moment is to do something like this:
>
> ```
> RequestEntity<Void> request = RequestEntity.post(url)
>     .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("foo", "bar").build();
> restTemplate.exchange(request, String.class);
> ```
>
> I'm inclined to agree with @wilkinsona that adding extra convince methods might not as useful as the current basicAuthorization method. That one is quite common, and when it was added was super painful to code yourself (it's now easier since Spring 4.3.1 added the BasicAuthorizationInterceptor class).
>
> We need to balance the convenience of any new convenience methods against the complexity of having too many ways to do the same thing. Since it's relatively easy to plug in a RestTemplateCustomizer for any application that want this behavior, I think we shouldn't add these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OAuth2RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html), which is tailored exactly for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me,

```
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add((outReq, bytes, clientHttpReqExec) -> {
            outReq.getHeaders().set(
                    HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token
                  );
                  return clientHttpReqExec.execute(outReq, bytes);
                });
restTemplate.getForObject(...
restTemplate.postForObject(....
```